# Django Model Design Help with Many2Many

Tags: django

I have a model class called Dashboard and it has an attribute 'team_members.' Like so:

```
class Dashboard(models.Model):
    ...
    team_members = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I am wondering is this the proper design? I am trying to say: A dashbooard has many team_members (user) and a user can be a team member of many dashboards.

Or, should I create a 2nd class that links the dashboards and team members? Something like so:

```
class TeamMember:
    members = m2m(Users)
    dashboards = m2m(Dashboard)
```

Thanks! :-)

Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first design does imply what you say. The second says that a `User` can be many `TemMember`s and vice versa, so isn't appropriate. You *could* use a one-to-one instead, but it wouldn't be needed if you didn't need to add more information about team members.

Comment: Great. So, the 2nd would be good if, say, I wanted to capture additional info about the team member? Let's say, the date they became a team member or who added them as a team member?

Comment: If you converted it to a one-to-one with `User`, yes.